# Playing media asynctask in a service cusses other asynctasks lock

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

I am having an AsyncTask to play media and I am using a Service for it. The problem is that when my AsyncTask (in the Service) is running, another part of the app that I used an AsyncTask to communicate with web server is not working until playing finishes. (Playing media not buffering it).

I have already tried removing the AsyncTask and using a new Thread but I can't update the UI in this mode.

What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want both an `Asynctask` and a `Service`. `Service`s are designed for long running background tasks. 'Asynctask's are designed to easily launch a new thread, perform some long-running task, and then send data to the UI thread.

There is only one UI thread, so, if you're updating the UI, you are blocking user interaction.

If you're streaming music, you would probably want a `Service` to spawn a new `Thread` so that it can constantly be downloading songs in the background. If, for example, the user presses a button and it loads a video, you might instead want an `Asynctask` to perform the download.

Generally, one might use an `Asynctask` to download a media file on user request (or, if you're downloading in the background, a `Service` might be used for this). Then the data is exchagned and the video file can be played using Android's `MediaPlayer`tools:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

Remember that, unlike with an `Asynctask`, creating a `Service` does not automatically mean that you have created a new `Thread`. `Service`s can run on the UI thread. Generally speaking, though, most use cases for `Service`s require that they launch a new `Thread` to do their work.

Comment: so whats your advice? how should i stream music (from a http url) and update UI in a same time?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used a **service** and a **handler** to create post delay